# sbt: publishing plugin to and resolving from local repo

Tags: sbt, ivy

I am trying to publish an sbt plugin to a local file repo. In the plugin's build.sbt I have:

```
publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("localtrix", file("/Users/jast/repo/localtrix")))
```

I run the `publish` task and it gets published fine to
`/Users/jast/repo/localtrix/org/me/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/1.2.3`

In another project, I want to resolve this plugin. in `project/plugins.sbt` I have:

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("localtrix", file("/Users/jast/repo/localtrix"))
addSbtPlugin("org.me" % "sbt-plugin" % "1.2.3")
```

I try to run sbt in the this project and I get:

```
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/jast/playspace/untitled38/project/"), "untitled38-build")...
[warn]  module not found: org.me#sbt-plugin;1.2.3
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.me/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.me/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml/2017.2+4-3037ba82+20180314-1919/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/jast/.ivy2/local/org.me/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/me/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/1.2.3/sbt-plugin-1.2.3.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/jast/.sbt/preloaded/org.me/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/jast/.sbt/preloaded/org/me/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/1.2.3/sbt-plugin-1.2.3.pom
[warn] ==== localtrix: tried
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.me#sbt-plugin;1.2.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

So how can I publish to a local repo it in a way that also gets resolved correctly?

Note: `publishLocal` and resolving from `.ivy2/local` works, but I want to be able to publish to a repo that I can copy to another machine without messing with that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sbt plugins by default are published ivy-style, so you when you refer to your local repository, use `Resolver.ivyStylePatterns`. To publish:

```
publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("localtrix", file("/Users/jast/repo/localtrix"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns))
```

And to resolve:

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("localtrix", file("/Users/jast/repo/localtrix"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
addSbtPlugin("org.me" % "sbt-plugin" % "1.2.3")
```

---

Alternatively you can set `publishMavenStyle := true` for the plugin, but I see that you already figured that out.

Comment: Thanks, this works. That it doesn't work with the configuration I originally tried seems to be a bug: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4015

Comment: Yeah, it's quite confusing that  `... at ...` is totally different from `Resolver.url`/`.file` and not just a shortcut for it. Even sbt devs [don't agree](https://github.com/sbt/librarymanagement/issues/224) about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed scala version in name. And you have also strange suffix in plugin name `_1.0` in your published artifact, so just fixing scala version could be not enough.

This should work.

```
addSbtPlugin("org.me" % "sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0" % "1.2.3")
```

If you find out where came this suffix `_1.0` from, fix on scala version should help:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.me" %% "sbt-plugin" % "1.2.3")
```

**Update after comment**

Ok, thanks, I did not know that for plugins it works differently.

But try to define resolver differently for resolvers (works for me):

```
resolvers += "localtrix" at "file:///Users/jast/repo/localtrix"
addSbtPlugin("org.me" % "sbt-plugin" % "1.2.3")
```

Comment: This is an sbt *plugin*, not a regular library. sbt adds the additional scala version and sbt version classifiers based on the sbt version. The `_1.0` here is the sbt binary version. These look differently depending on whether it is trying to resolve from an ivy or maven repo. The question here is why sbt can't resolve from the same place that it published to locally. Also note that resolving after doing `publishLocal` does work, so it can't be that the `addSbtPlugin` part is wrong.

Comment: @JustinKaeser Did not know that, thanks. Updated answer with solution

Comment: Okay, that was one part to make it work. Also necessary: in the plugin's build.sbt, add `publishMavenStyle := true`. Now it can be resolved as a Maven artifact!